# On which open intervals are the following functions linearly dependent? (Hyperbolic functions)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions

On which open intervals are the following functions linearly dependent: 
$f(x) = \operatorname{cosh}^2x$, $g(x) = 2$, $h(x) = \operatorname{sinh}^2x?$

I tried wronskian (to find out whether independent) and it turned out to be $0$ so it doesn't tell me anything (assuming I calculated correctly).

I tried solving straight from definition - that is checking if for some interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ there are real ${\alpha}, {\beta}, {\gamma}$, not all of them zeros, such that ${\alpha}\operatorname{cosh}^2x + 2{\beta} + {\gamma}\operatorname{sinh}^2x = 0$ for all $x \in I$. I could not make it work. Then I checked for the simpler linear dependence ${\alpha}\operatorname{cosh}^2x + {\beta}\operatorname{sinh}^2x = 0$ and wound up with the equation $e^{2x} + e^{-2x} = {\frac{2(\beta-\alpha)}{\beta+\alpha}}$.

Any advice on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1
$$

For every $x$. The wronskian is a nuclear option.

Comment: So that simply means ${\alpha}=1, {\beta}=-2$ and ${\gamma}=-1$ solves it?

Comment: (Just notice the question was about their linear dependence not independence). It means that they are linearly dependent on any open interval?

Comment: @Friedman It's true but doesn't solve it. If that identity holds for every $x$, what is an open interval in which the functions are LD?

Comment: $(-\infty, \infty)?$

Comment: @Friedman hooray!

Comment: @Friedman All the best!